# Why am I not able to populate my Images to my tables in my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am attempting to display the image for each car on my table. When I run the code, the View crashes and I get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have images saved on my database and they are linked to the car so I am not sure why I am getting null value.

This is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<IgnitionHub2._0.Models.Car>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageList.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MarketValue)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model.Make.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
    <td>
        <img src=@String.Format("/CarImages/{0}",item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Title) />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarketValue)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model.Make.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CarID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CarID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CarID })
    </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is the controller

```
public ActionResult _Index()
{
    var cars = new List<Car>(db.Cars); 
    return PartialView(cars);
}
```

These are the models:

```
namespace IgnitionHub2._0.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class Car
    {
            public Car()
            {
            }

            public int CarID { get; set; }
            public string Year { get; set; }
            public string Color { get; set; }
            public string Mileage { get; set; }
            public string BodyType { get; set; }
            public string Drive { get; set; }
            public string Notes { get; set; }
            public bool Available { get; set; }
            public string VinNumber { get; set; }
            public int CarLotID { get; set; }
            public int ModelID { get; set; }
            public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
            public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Car> SelectedCar { get; set; }
            public virtual Image ImageList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the model for Image

```
namespace IgnitionHub2._0.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class Image
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public int CarID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }        
        public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase[] files { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My application crashes when It get to the `@foreach (var item in Model)` in the view.

Please Help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend **not** to store something like `HttpPostedFileBase` in your model class! You should **only** store the actual bytes of the car's image - as a `byte[]`.

Comment: debug and find whether the `Model` is null or not

Comment: try eager loading car images here like `db.Cars.Include(x=>x.Images).ToList()`.

Comment: @NithinChandran Model is not null, I added breakpoint and was able to see the following `System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(...) returned null.`

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh I added that code but I still have the same issue

Comment: @SmileyRod are you using Code First ? If Yes can you share the configuration of cars ?

Comment: I used database first @GhanshyamSingh

Comment: If I comment out `<td> <img src=@String.Format("/CarImages/{0}",item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Title) />
    </td>` the application runs fine

Comment: in database table foreign key exists, Right ? I think its an issue with foreign key

Comment: There is foreign key for cars in Image table @GhanshyamSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make my code work by changing

```
<td>
    <img src=@String.Format("/CarImages/{0}",item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Title) />
</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
    @if (item.Images.Count > 0)
    {<img src=@String.Format("/CarImages/{0}", item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Title) />}
</td>
```